# TeamCity cli requests

Tags: bash, curl, teamcity

I'm trying to trigger job via REST API in TeamCity, but cannot understand how to specify branch names. For example I have 2 VCSs:

```
VCS1 name = vcs1
branch1 name = branch1
VCS2 name = vcs2
branch2 name = branch2
```

Now I can successful trigger job, but need to specify exact branches:

```
curl -u username:password --request POST http://tc.domain.com:9090/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=JobName
```

How to add branch names to this request?

Comment: Have you researched on the documentation of the API? For sure you'll find where to insert the branch name.

Comment: @samthegolden if I didn't made research, then how I could write that request? I cannot understand how I should mention VCS name and branch name name in it.